# Snapping points to lines returns unexpected results

Tags: postgis, point, line, linestring, points-to-line

I have a linenetwork `lines` and a lot of points `points`.
The table `lines` has 42869 rows, the table `points` has 11264 rows. I am trying to snap each point to its closes line.

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    ST_Distance(l.geom, p.geom) as distance,
    ST_ClosestPoint(l.geom, p.geom) as geom 
FROM
    lines AS l,
    points AS p;
```

This returns me selection with 482876416 rows, which is 42869 * 11264.

I can solve it with a `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(p.id) p.id,
    ST_Distance(l.geom, p.geom) as distance,
    ST_ClosestPoint(l.geom, p.geom) as geom 
FROM
    lines AS l,
    points AS p;
```

But I want to know: Why is it doing that? I would expect the result table to have the sname number of rows as my `points` table when not using a `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: I closed this question as duplicate, and in favor, of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436976/how-to-snap-points-to-line.