# How to snap points to line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, line, knn

I am having a table `lines` being `MULTILINESTRING` (2 Dimensions) and a table `points` being `MULTIPOINT` (3 Dimensions). The two are in the same `CRS`.
Now, I am trying to snap all the points to the closest line.

[image: Points not on line]

I run this query

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(p.id) p.id,
    ST_Distance(l.geom, p.geom) as distance,
    ST_ClosestPoint(l.geom, p.geom) as geom 
FROM
    lines AS l,
    points AS p;
```

Which runs through and returns a table with the same number of rows as the `points` table.
However, upon inspecting the result, I see that all the points (11246 in total) are snapped to one line, overlaying each other.

[image: Points snapped to line after query]

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This question is directly related [to your earlier one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/436974/93656), making it a duplicate - since this one is also addressing an unexpected outcome further downstream the core issue of both posts, I'll answer here.*

---

The core issue with your attempt is the implicit `CROSS JOIN`, which creates a *cartesian product* between both tables:

```
[...]
FROM
  <table_a>,    -- implicit CROSS JOIN using , (comma) notation
  <table_b>
[...]
```

which translates to:

> Join **each row** in `<table_a>` ***to each row*** of `<table_b>`.

and returns **`COUNT(<table_a>) * COUNT(<table_b>)`** rows in its result set.

Now, the attempted `DISTINCT ON (p.id)` successfully reduces this *cartesian product* of both tables to the *distinct `p.id` values of `points AS p`*, but since there are `COUNT(lines)` rows for every `p.id` in the result set, PostgreSQL has to choose one of them to satisfy the `DISTINCT` command - and it does that *by picking the first row that is given by the inherent order of the `lines` table*, per `p.id`; in your case this is the same `lines.geom` for every distinct `p.id`.

---

The requirement for a ***(k) Nearest Neighbor*** search can be expressed as

> For **every row** in `<table_a>` find **the *k* closest row(s)** in `<table_b>`.

which is logically equivalent to a procedural `FOR LOOP` - and which can be realized with a `LATERAL` join within PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
  ST_ClosestPoint(n.geom, p.geom) AS geom
  ST_Distance(n.geom, p.geom) AS dist
FROM
  points AS p
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      l.geom
    FROM
      lines AS l
    ORDER BY
      l.geom <-> p.geom
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS n
;
```

---

I recommend to [further read](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knn+postgis) on multiple topics concerning *(K)NN* queries, to understand **`LATERAL` queries, distances and index usage**.

**Related:**

- [Finding nearest neighbor for each point in the same table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287774/nearest-neighbor/287810#287810)
- [PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/postgis-st-closestpoint-join-error/352905#352905)
- [Optimizing my script; taking too long; distance between many objects PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268025/optimizing-my-script-taking-too-long-distance-between-many-objects-postgis/268168#268168)
- [Speedup function to calculate distance from centroid of building to river segment in PostgreSQL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/337896/speedup-function-to-calculate-distance-from-centroid-of-building-to-river-segmen/337939#337939)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought these might be different questions, but I understand now, that they are different. Is there a way to "see" if a PostGIS function uses a `CROSS JOIN`? Looking at the documentation, it is not clear to me that PostGIS does that.

Comment: @Stophface oh that is nothing a function does, see [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html) on `JOIN`s. Let me add: `JOIN` behaviors and their set-theoretic differences are *at the very heart of RDBs* - and I urge you to do yourself a favor and make yourself familiar with the core concepts of relational data models, to being able to properly operate PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your issue ,)

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted but forgot to accept! I understand `JOIN`s, but looking at the documentation I did not expect to need a `JOIN`. I assumed that this is done internally, returning me the closes point on the line. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @Stophface ah, okay. No, the set-theoretic dependencies between relations are usually far beyond the scope and responsibilities of a regular, functional API like the PostGIS function family. The idea here is to limit the functionality to result set manipulation, and index access for filter expressions, to support the highest customization, tuning and extensibility of query expressions.