# pgr_withPointsCost returns incorrect table values

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, geometric-network

I have been struggling with getting **pgr_withPointsCost** to output a correct cost table for months.  I have created a routable network, ensured the network is connected, created a poi table with all the required fields, but it only outputs a single output whose distance isn't correct. Everything is in EPSG 3400.

For the poi table (migration.cntrlpts_move), I have moved all the points to the line network, set the pid column to have a negative value as required.  It should start at id = 1 (pid=-1) and end at id = 6 (pid = -6)

| id | fraction | edge_id | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1790 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1792 | -2 |
| 3 | 0.98 | 3319 | -3 |
| 4 | 0.27 | 2244 | -4 |
| 5 | 0.406 | 3523 | -5 |
| 6 | 0 | 4020 | -6 |

The output table looks like this:

| start_pid | end_pid | agg_cost | id | fraction | geom | edge_id | pid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 215.0217 | 2 | 1 | 0101000020480D000083BD86371B15144165D5F8130F375741 | 1792 | 2 |

The following are all the steps:

```
Step 1: Create Routable Network

-- ### Step 1 - Create Topology of imported streams layer ###
-- Build topology for stream CCP distance calculations
ALTER TABLE migration.streams ADD COLUMN "source" integer; -- add source column for pg routing
ALTER TABLE migration.streams ADD COLUMN "target" integer; -- add target column for pg routing
SELECT pgr_createTopology('migration.streams', 1.0, 'geom', 'id');

-- ### Step 2 - Add pgRouting networking information
ALTER TABLE migration.streams ADD COLUMN length float8; -- add length field for pgr cost
ALTER TABLE migration.streams ADD COLUMN cost float8; -- add cost column
ALTER TABLE migration.streams ADD COLUMN reverse_cost float8; -- add reverse_cost column

UPDATE migration.streams SET length = ST_Length(geom);
UPDATE migration.streams SET cost = ST_length(geom); 
UPDATE migration.streams SET reverse_cost = -1; 

-- ### Step 4 - Move release and CCP locations to stream and calculate fraction of stream CCP is located on
-- We first need to get a candidate set of maybe-closest stream, ordered by id and distance.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS migration.control_pts_events;
CREATE TABLE migration.control_pts_events AS
WITH ordered_nearest AS (
SELECT
  ST_GeometryN(streams.geom,1) AS streams_geom,
  streams.id AS streams_id,
  pts.geom AS pts_geom,
  pts.id AS pts_id,
  pts.ccp_no,
  pts.pipeline,
  pts.vel_lo,
  pts.vel_hi,
  ST_Distance(streams.geom, pts.geom) AS distance_to_stream
FROM migration.streams streams
  JOIN migration.ccp pts                        -- *** change to shapefile name ***
  ON ST_DWithin(streams.geom, pts.geom, 500)    -- *** search distance away from stream ***
ORDER BY pts_id, distance_to_stream ASC
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (pts_id)
  pts_id,
  streams_id,
  ST_LineLocatePoint(streams_geom, pts_geom) AS fraction,
  distance_to_stream
FROM ordered_nearest;


-- Table for pgr_withPointsCost operation with the fraction of the stream a point is on & stream edge_id.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS migration.cntrlpts_move;
CREATE TABLE migration.cntrlpts_move AS
SELECT
  events.pts_id AS id, events.fraction,
  ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_GeometryN(streams.geom, 1), events.fraction) AS geom,
  events.streams_id AS edge_id
FROM migration.control_pts_events events
JOIN migration.streams streams
ON (streams.id = events.streams_id);

-- Update control points table to include -pid
ALTER TABLE migration.cntrlpts_move ADD COLUMN "pid" bigint;        -- add pid column for pg routing
UPDATE migration.cntrlpts_move SET pid = id;


-- Cost path from ccp to ccp
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS migration.ccp_cost;
CREATE TABLE migration.ccp_cost AS
WITH pgr_ccp AS (
SELECT r.*, p.*
FROM   pgr_withPointsCost(
         'SELECT id, 
                 source, 
                 target, 
                 length AS cost, 
                 reverse_cost
                 FROM migration.streams',
         'SELECT pid*-1 AS pid, 
                 edge_id, 
                 fraction 
                 FROM migration.cntrlpts_move WHERE pid < 0',
            (SELECT pid FROM migration.cntrlpts_move WHERE id = 1),             -- start location id number
            ARRAY(SELECT pid FROM migration.cntrlpts_move WHERE id > 1),        -- not equal to start location
            directed => true) AS r INNER JOIN migration.cntrlpts_move AS p ON
            r.end_pid = p.pid;
    ), ccp_distances AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_ccp 
    )
    SELECT * FROM ccp_distances ORDER BY agg_cost;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update, having access to exemplary data:**

While my answer is still valid for your presented query, there is another issue with your setup that is not very well documented: your `Point SQL` produces vertices that *are **considered** to **not** actually be **outside** of the graph*, i.e. where `ST_LineLocatePoint` is either `0.0` or `1.0` - and *pgRouting*s graph engine is rather picky about this when called with the `withPoints` family of functions.

The general idea here is that to switch using the `pid` of the closest *regular* vertex instead of an *outside* `pid` whenever the `fraction` is either `0` or `1`. The sophisticated solution would include a conditional check on a prepared POI table to identify *outside* points that project onto *regular* vertices, and

- avoid them in the `Points SQL` with a filter
- use the respective *regular* `pid`s in the `from_pid/to_pid` conditionally

A sufficiently precise workaround is to simply de- or increase the fraction in those cases, e.g. using my query below:

```
...
CASE WHEN stm._frac = 0.0 THEN 0.0000001 WHEN stm._frac = 1.0 THEN 0.9999999 ELSE stm._frac END AS fraction,
...
```

---

When you run

```
UPDATE migration.cntrlpts_move SET pid = id;
```

the `pid`s are ***not** negative* - however, you ***assume they are***, both

- in the `Point SQL`, where you are *negating* them again to be *positive*

  - *here they have to be **positive***
- when passing in `start_/stop_vertices`, where you are *not* negating them

  - *here they have to be **negative***

Seeing that the result lists only *positive* `pid`s it is obvious that `pgr_withPointsCost` routes between *regular topology vertices* only - if it were routing between `Point SQL` vertices (only), both `start_pid` & `end_pid` in the results would be *negative*.

---

**Notes:**

- no need to actually "*move*" the `migration.ccp` geometries; the `Point SQL` requires only the *fraction of line length* at which each `ccp.geom` projects onto its nearest `streams.geom`
- use a more streamlined (and highly efficient) *(K)NN* query to find the closest `streams.geom` to each `ccp.geom` - some references:

  - within an `UPDATE`: 
     [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)
  - generally (and also comparing to your `DISTINCT ON` approach): 
     [How to snap points to line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/436976/how-to-snap-points-to-line/436995#436995)
- be extremely cautious about using `MULTI` geometries - since you are using `ST_GeometryN` I assume this is the case - as their network topology rules are undefined

---

**Bonus:**

You could simplify your setup significantly after `Step 1`:

```
-- ### Step 2 - Create cost matrix
SELECT
  cmx.*,
  pts.*
FROM
  pgr_withPointsCost(
    -- Edge SQL - populating 'cost'/'reverse_cost' on the fly
    $$
    SELECT
      id,
      source,
      target,
      ST_Length(geom) AS cost,
      -1 AS reverse_cost
    FROM
      migration.streams
    $$,
    -- Point SQL - populating 'fraction' on the fly (via (K)NN sub-query)
    $$
    SELECT
      pts.id AS pid,
      stm.id AS edge_id,
      stm._frac AS fraction
    FROM
      migration.ccp AS pts
      CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
          _stm.id,
          ST_LineLocatePoint(_stm.geom, pts.geom) AS _frac
        FROM
          migration.streams AS _stm
        ORDER BY
          _stm.geom <-> pts.geom
        LIMIT
          1
      ) AS stm
    $$,
    -- 'start_pid' - negating on the fly
    (
      SELECT
        -id
      FROM
        migration.ccp
      WHERE
        id = 1
    ),
    -- 'end_pids' - negating on the fly
    (
      SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(-id)
      FROM
        migration.ccp
      WHERE
        id > 1
    )
  ) AS cmx
  JOIN
  migration.ccp AS pts
    ON -(cmx.end_pid) = pts.id  -- -(-n) = n
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I tried the above and I still can't get it to route.  I get a blank table. I'm just not getting it.  Sorry :(

Comment: @MJM Can you post a subset of your data as an example?

Comment: https://github.com/EPPResponse/pgr_problem

Comment: @MJM check my update!

Comment: I tried the update and received a blank table.  I create the stream topology, then run step 2, the cost matrix, correct?

Comment: @MJM https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148970/discussion-between-geozelot-mjm